# How can I access webfig of my mikrotik routerboard?

Tags: router, mikrotik-routeros

To connect to web config on mikrotik routerboard I need the ip address of my routerboard but the problem is that I don't know the ip address of my routerboard. Is there anyway I can get the ip address of my routerboard in other to connect to the webfig?

Comment: Look into the docs, there should be a default address be listed (possibly 192.168.88.1).

Comment: Have tried 192.168.88.1 n I checked d docs but nothing has happened

Comment: How is your PC's network interface configured and how do you connect it to the device?

Comment: I connect to the device through an application called winbox using ethernet port(cable). The winbox searches for the routerboard device then I click connect. A new app will pop up which allows me to configure my routerboard. The first thing I did on the routerboard was to reset the configuration. I don't know if this has in anyway affect the ip address of my routerboard

Answer (score 3):

You can find out the IP address with the program **winbox**,if you are connected to a port where discovery is enabled.

http://www.mikrotik.com/download (under "Useful tools and utilities")

Look at the tab "neighbors" - (in the older version of winbox - version 2 - it's the button with three dots)

If the IP is in a different subnet then you can connect via mac address